# Compare List<String> items to String

Tags: android, list, compare

I am getting DB values with following code:

```
public List<String> getPlayerNames() {
        List<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PLAYERS",null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String q = c.getString(1);
            playerNames.add(q);

        }
        c.close();
        myDataBase.close();
        return playerNames;

    }
```

I now want to compare the items in this List to a String value with following method:

```
private boolean checkIfExists(String newPlayer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<String> playerNames = myDbHelper.getPlayerNames();
        //here a loop?! 

        return false;
    }
```

But I don't really know how to compare these list items with a string value. I tried with a for loop, but then again, a list doesn't support a .length() method to go trough all elements? Tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(String playerName : playerNames){
  if(playerName.equals(newPlayer)){
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, I used @David M 's tip and used equalsIgnoreCase(). The structure of the loop is logic indeed. Is it also possible to use this structure on arrays, just as interest...

Comment: One minor question: Suppose I want to use these values, I guess I can do that with a while loop? Correct?

Comment: Which values do you want to use?

Comment: For example, I want to use the name itself to put it in a listview... Or is using this for loop also ok, but instead of the if statement, to link to a listview?

Comment: I actually think you should create another question for that, the this is going a little off-topic. But, yes you could use the playerName for whatever you need, the thing is that playerName could be the EXACT same as newPlayer that you already have.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String playerName : playerNames) {
   if (playerName.equals(newPlayer)) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

you might want `equalsIgnoreCase()` rather than `equals()`

Comment: No if without brackets, EVER.

Answer (score 2):

yes there will be a loop like below

```
for(String str : players)
{
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(newPlayer))
    { 
      return true; 
    } 
}
return false;
```

Comment: You should put the return flase outside the foreach or the method would return false after the first comparison.

Comment: I just want to show the logic and wrote fast :) thanx for correction

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to recognize a foreach loop? Is that possible? :s

Comment: If I remember correctly the foreach loop is C# and Android uses Java, so a for(<Type> tmp : collection) would be the same.

Comment: No you are right , it must be FOR not foreach, as i said before because i want to show logic , i didnt paid attantion to spelling :) I tought in c#

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with case sensitive strings

```
for(String playerName : playerNames){
  if(playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(newPlayer)){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers so far.  This is one of those "another way of doing it" solutions for completeness.

You could think about using a Set.

```
public Set<String> getPlayerNames() {
    TreeSet<String> playerNames = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Then use

```
if (playerNames.contains(newPlayer)){}
```

It is then also easy to control the case sensitivity of the set, even at runtime if it made sense.

[EDIT]

That said, your question could have been "What is the correct way to design an app that let's me create, delete and modify players, the details of which are stored in a SQLite datbase?".  You didn't ask that question, but I'll answer it anyway because that question should have been asked before this one.

Spend some time Googling for "software design patterns", especially MVC (Model View Controller).  MVC is a standard pattern used in many Android apps.  The Model is real world data you want to work with (players).  The View(s) are the interface of your app, ListViews, TextViews etc.  The controllers (Java adapters) are the things that bind the two together and control how data is delivered to your UI and how changes are made back into the data.

At the moment, you've got a little guy, about 3 inches tall, standing on your left shoulder saying "Show me what you've got.  I want to see this running on my phone as quickly as possible.  Get it done and figure out the bugs later".  He's also very shouty and difficult to ignore.

If you look really closely, you'll see another little guy on your right shoulder saying "Get the design right first.  Then start building the app.  I don't mind waiting a little while because the end result will be better".  This guy speaks with a much quieter voice and is often not very assertive.

Your job is to set fire to the guy on the left so that he runs away and feed Ben and Jerrys' Phish Food ice cream to the guy on right so that he hangs around and gives you more good advice.

So let's listen to the guy on the right for a while:

"Well Matthias, there are lots of ways of approaching this but as you're learning, let's stick with the common approach.  This will make it easy to Google to find the individual components you need to stitch it together.

You've already got a database with a Players table that holds data about the Players.  Let's create a class in our code which also represents a player.

```
public class Player{
      public int id;
      public String name;
      public Boolean likesPhishFood;
}
```

Now, when we start our app, we can load the data from the table into our app so that can start to work with it.  How about using an Adapter?  We can then use a Cursor to query our database which we can use to create an adapter, maybe SimpleCursorAdapter, then finally bind our adapter to the ListView.  Later, you can add onClickListener and onLongClickListener to do something when the user clicks a Player in the list.

The advantage of all this is that your code, without any question, will eventually lead to producing your app in less time; will be much easier to read; will have fewer bugs and, perhaps most importantly, will be easier to change.

I can pretty much guarantee that at some point, usually about half way through, you are going to want to add a bit of data about a Player.  Maybe the number of times they've played, or that they have blue eyes.  With an MVC design, these kind of changes are much easier to do, and less prone to creating new bugs, than digging through your code looking for ArrayLists and for loops that you need to change to accommodate the new data.

Sure, it will take you more time before your app is ready to look at but what you'll learn along the way will pay back the investment many times - in this app and other apps you do in the future."

Listen to the guy on the right.  He talks sense.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Good luck.

Comment: I must say, I am a rookie and this is quite difficult for me to understand :) What is the difference between a Set and TreeSet?

Comment: Just to be a little picky in this case I don't think a Set should be used. Sets doesn't allow repetitions and it could happen that two players had the same name. But actually a contains() should also work directly on the List so the contains() solution would be even better.

Comment: Set is the general interface. TreeSet is an implementation of said interface using a Tree.

Comment: List.contains() uses the default comparator of the list type so is case sensitive for String.  You could extend String and provide your own comparator but that said, if duplicate names is an issue then using the name as the key is a bad idea and all of the implementations using an ArrayList will fail since the loop exits when any match is found.  If this was me, first thing I would do is `class Player{}`

Comment: Thanks Simon! I must say, indeed I created a table players which holds the info. Of course, considering it's my first app I have some things to learn :) I never heard of MVC, i'll look into that.. I might just wait to use it for my next app.. This one is almost finished (I know, it is faster :))

Comment: Almost finished, yeh right ;)  The key point was not so much the players table as the Player class.  That's the key to the kingdom.

Comment: It really is actually... I am just building a way to use the app with a different profile.. But as I said, I will look into it, tonight, and try to start from a better basis the next app... just out of curiousity, have you made apps with this basis? And are they on the market? Grts!

Comment: Yes and yes.  I don't want to link to them because I want my contributions here (and my takeaways) to remain separate.  And I was just kidding about almost finished.  To most developers, me included, that means a month or two ;)